# UILabel not resizing after scaling font using minimumScaleFactor

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, snapkit

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` that I want to dynamically adjust its font and size based on content to always maintain the largest font that it can support without truncating. I am most of the way there using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, but the label has extra vertical space that it does not need.

In this screenshot running on the iPhone SE simulator, the label correctly scaled the font down from 55 to fit, but there is this extra space at the top of the label. I want that space to go away!

[image]

Here is my label code:

```
private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 55, weight: .ultraLight)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.25
        label.backgroundColor = .purple
        return label
    }()
```

Here is my layout code:

```
self.addSubview(self.labelsContainerView)
self.labelsContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.equalTo(leftView.snp.trailing).offset(20)
    make.trailing.equalTo(rightView.snp.leading).offset(-20)
    make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}

self.labelsContainerView.addSubview(self.middleLabel)
self.middleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.trailing.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}

self.labelsContainerView.addSubview(self.topLabel)
self.topLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.equalToSuperview()
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.middleLabel.snp.top)
    make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(8)
}

self.labelsContainerView.addSubview(self.bottomLabel)
self.bottomLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.leading.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(self.middleLabel.snp.bottom)
    make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-8)
}
```

In short, I have a `UIView` pinned to the top and bottom of my `UITableViewCell`. Inside that view, I have 3 labels: top, middle, and bottom. The labels are pinned top-to-bottom.

I want `middleLabel` to always be the largest size it can be to satisfy layout and use the largest font that will fit inside that size without truncating. It seems almost like the intrinsic content size isn't being updated when the label's font changes. I have tried all kinds of calls to `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` but they never helped.

Comment: Your top and bottom labels constraints to the middle label end up enlarging the middle label. I would suggest trying out the greater than or equal on the constraint between bottom and middle label.

Comment: Interesting, I had been really focused on the constraints and properties of my middle label that I didn't really consider the effects of the other label constraints. I will play around with some of those constraints. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It will take some extra work to get the label's **Height** to change, but if you only need the text vertically centered, add this to your label configuration:

```
label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

Here's the difference... top uses default `.alignBaselines` bottom uses `.alignCenters`:

[image]

Comment: Honestly, not something I had considered. I still would prefer that space to get tightened up, but this is at least a fallback option instead of fighting a losing battle. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Somethings are hard enough or simply impossible to achieve because of the way constraints are designed. The best option available would be calculating the exact size required for the middle label using the good old way considering fonts and fix width to get the height. And then set height and width constraints.